# Need explanation why the following code spans for infinity

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner to python and was wondering why the code spans for infinity when it should've been stopped at 1.

```
def main():
    i = 0.0
    while i != 1.0:
        print("i =", i)
        i += 0.1
main()
```

Comment: floating point accumulation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is a well known problem in Python.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Your variable `i` never becomes exactly 1, but instead becomes 0.9999999999999999.

Do instead:

```
def main():
    i = 0.0
    while i <= 1.0:
        print("i =", i)
        i += 0.1
```

Comment: I would not call it a problem with python, rather a problem with binary representations of decimal numbers.

Comment: i = 0.0
    i = 0.1
    i = 0.2
    i = 0.30000000000000004
    i = 0.4
i = 0.5
    i = 0.6
    i = 0.7
    i = 0.7999999999999999
    i = 0.8999999999999999
    i = 0.9999999999999999

Comment: You asked why it acts as it does, not how to correct it. I am, however, happy to oblige: replace `i += 0.1` with `i = round(i+0.1, 1)`

Comment: Thanks..Sorry if I sounded rude.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, of course you shouldn't compare floats by equality, but there's more to it: when you're adding like this you get floating point accumulation error.

You can use an integer counter instead and apply multiplication every time to avoid that.

```
def main():
    i = 0.0
    count = 0
    while i < 1.0:
        print("i =", i)
        count += 1
        i = count*0.1

main()
```

I have replaced `i != 1.0` by `i < 1.0` because that's all you need, but it even works with `!=` (although I don't recommend that) now because there's no accumulation error anymore the way it's computed with the integer counter.

Comment: i = 0.6000000000000001
i = 0.7000000000000001

Comment: why am I seeing  0.6000000000000001 instead of 0.6 ?

Comment: floating point representation, don't worry about that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken